# Why is this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Why is this question put on hold as off topic? [Chihiro's name turning to Sen [on hold]](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70301/chihiros-name-turning-to-sen)

This question is probably one of the most pertinent questions in regards to this movie. The name of this movie in Japanese is the foundation of what this movie is about and the question is asking probably one of the most important questions that could be asked.  Just because no one understands it is no reason to have it put on hold.

The name of the movie in Japanese to English is `sen to Chihiro no
kami kakushi` , `sen=千 to Chihiro=千尋 no
kami=神 kakushi=隠し` Directly translating the title is very hard. The name `sen=千 と=to Chihiro=千尋` is the most important thing in this movie. The question asks why does `sen=千` remains when `yubaba` take it away; it is because that is what remains of the name `Chihiro=千尋`.

You all need a new system of evaluating why a question should be put on hold.

Comment: I wasn't involved in closing that question, but I think first sentence in that question made others think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55677/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-kyloren).

Answer (score 4):

**The question has been reopened.**

By user AJ and moderator Ankit Sharma: https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/70301/revisions

(I'm not sure why nobody answered this meta question back then, when it was reopened, but I'm posting an answer now so that at least this can be marked as answered.)